# group by based on two columns with same but vice versa values

Tags: mysql

**What I Have:**
I have a table where I have two basic columns on which the query is supposed to work

```
c1|c2
1   2
2   1
1   3
3   1
2   4
```

Now I want the result after the execution of the query is this

```
c1|c2
2   1
3   1
```

Notice 
  (3,1) was the last occurence of 1 and 3 no matter in which order they are as along as it is 1 and 3 and same is (2,1)

How can I achieve this where one value of the two columns is static for example in this case (1) is static and I want only those rows which has (1) in any of the two columns in their last occurrence.. Can any one help ?

Comment: I assume you also want (2, 4) in the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nope .. not (2,4) .. well yeah if 2 or 4 was the the number i select to be constant